# Debian's security tracker says a CVE is fixed, while BlackDuck scanner detects it

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, docker, debian, glibc

I stumbled across a vulnerability considered a critical security risk (CVE-2023-25139) in one of container images I build.

Debian's security tracker states it's fixed: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-25139 - specifically, in Debian Sid with glibc 2.37-12, while BlackDuck says it's still there. I know false positives are possible, and normally I check the package's changelog when in doubt. Normally CVEs are listed there when the package is patched to fix them.

I've checked the changelog: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/g/glibc/glibc_2.37-12_changelog - and there's nothing there about CVE-2023-25139.

Now if it wasn't listed as fixed in their security tracker, I'd expect it's going to be fixed later, in a week or two, but it seems like Debian thinks everything's fine while BlackDuck doesn't and I don't understand what's actually going on there.

Is there anything else I should check, apart from the security tracker and the changelog? Cross-check it with other scanners (e.g. trivy doesn't detect it)? Maybe I misunderstand Debian's security patching process, had it been in the changelog, I'd have that going for my image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the security page says that it's fixed in 2.37-**13** for Debian side, rather than 2.37-12 as you say in your question. So the changelog you should be looking at is:

https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/g/glibc/glibc_2.37-13_changelog

But your point still stands - the changelog for that version doesn't mention that specific CVE either.

---

Other vulnerability scanners probably aren't going to be much use, as they're likely to be using the same data sources as the one you've already used. And if Trivy says one things and BlackDuck says another, you still don't know which one is right.

There's a good chance that this is just an oversight and it's been missed from the changelog - so your easiest option would be to reach out to the package maintainer and ask them to confirm whether that specific CVE was resolved (as the security team think it was) in that version. And then hopefully between them and the security team, they can work out what the current status is and update either the changelog or the security page to reflect that.

Otherwise, you'll need to investigate yourself. That could mean either inspecting the source code of that package to see if the fix has been applied, or testing the compiled binary to see if it still appears to be vulnerable.

Comment: When I was posting the question, it was 'fixed in 2.37-12', they've released 2.37.13 since.

Comment: For some reason, I overlooked the opportunity to research it myself, you're right. So now my understanding is, based on this: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30068 and the `release/2-37/master` branch from here: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git is **as of now** they fixed some aspects of the vulnerability and documented the rest. Despite Debian showing it's 'fixed', I should go with BlackDuck's readings and check for new releases once in a while, until the CVE fixed entry is in the changelog. I guess it's just how I should treat CVEs in Debain going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Since the bug report contains simple snippets to test the behaviour you can simply copy the examples, compile them locally, run them and observe the output. This is why working proof of concept and exploits are so useful, it saves us from guessing.
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30068

Comment: Thanks, indeed there were POCs there, and I should have tried them for myself first. The only reason I'm not accepting this as an answer is it's not always the case, quite often POCs are not published or are obfuscated in some manner so it's not something you can always rely on, while most of the time git log and e.g. mailing lists or bug trackers are available.

Comment: Sadly this is all to true, and even harder to analyse in closed source when there is no working exploit/poc available. I blame the "responsible disclosure" endorsers for a lot of this.